# Word 2010 VBA applying styles but not changing font

Tags: vba, microsoft-word-2010

I don't use VBA that often, and I'm trying to put together a macro which selects all text in the document with font size 13.5 pt and changes its style to Header 1. So far I have the below code:

```
Sub FormatSectionHeaders()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim oRng As Word.Range
    Set oRng = ActiveDocument.Content
    oRng.Find.ClearFormatting
    oRng.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    oRng.Find.Replacement.Style = wdStyleHeading1
    With oRng.Find
     .Font.Size = 13.5
     .Text = ""
     .Execute Format:=True, Replace:=wdReplaceAll, Wrap:=wdFindContinue
    End With
End Sub
```

This selects the correct text and applies the style, but for some reason it is not overriding all of the original formatting - the font and font size, for instance, are not changed to match those of the style. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Note: I can get this to work with the following loop, but this is a lot slower than using replaceall, so I'd like to try and fix the code above rather than using something like this.

```
With oRng.Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Text = ""
    .Font.Size = 13.5
    While .Execute
        oRng.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles(wdStyleHeading1)
        oRng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    Wend
End With
```

Comment: I was able to get this to work by explicitly forcing the text to take on the font and paragraph formatting values of the style through the following code:
`oRng.Find.Replacement.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles(wdStyleHeading1)
oRng.Find.Replacement.Font = ActiveDocument.Styles(wdStyleHeading1).Font
oRng.Find.Replacement.ParagraphFormat = ActiveDocument.Styles(wdStyleHeading1).ParagraphFormat`
However, this still doesn't explain why the text was not taking these on just through the application of the style, so any explanation on that would be most welcome.

Comment: It seems that this, and other issues I was experiencing with my VBA code, were due to the fact that the text being altered was inside a cell of a large (invisible) table. On transferring text only to another document, the issues were resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that this, and other issues I was experiencing with my VBA code, were due to the fact that the text being altered was inside a cell of a large (invisible) table. On transferring text only to another document, the issues were resolved. See the comments for a way to force the style to take effect even within the cell.

Answer (score 0):

You are finding the content which have font size of 13.5 and you are trying to apply the heading1 style for that content. but in word document default template(Normal) It have the first level heading style as Heading1 so you can use the code like below

oRng.style = "Heading1"

Comment: How is `oRng.style = "Heading1"` different from `oRng.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles(wdStyleHeading1)` (why do you think it will improve the speed)?